# Unity Prevent Jump if Button was clicked

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a Menu scene where the Player can Jump. Just for fun before the real Game begins. The Game begins with click on an UI-Button. But if I click the Button, the Player Jumps just before the new Scene is loaded. I want to prevent that. So I have to check, before my Jump, if no Button was clicked. Any Ideas how to do that?

I tried it with a static variable. But the problem is, that the Script that calls the Jump Function runs first. Before the Buttonscript where I can set the Variable to false.

```
void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck1.position, 0.15f, groundLayer);

    // Here I want to check if the click doesnt hit a button
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isGrounded)
    {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

        // Here I set Jump to true, so my FixedUpdate Method can execute the Jump
        jump = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple.

Check if the mouse is over a GUI element:

`EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`

So

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) 
&& isGrounded 
&& !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
```

This checks to make sure that if they clicked the mouse and they were not over a GUI element, then the player can jump.

As an aside, when you get big conditionals like this, it's a good idea to break them up into helper methods.

Comment: Thank you!! So simple -.- But i just started to develop in Unity. You helped a lot. I will mark this as answered as soon as i can. (7 minute delay)